# Django : Stop calling same view if it's already called

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a view, and when user click on a button it gets called. But if a user clicks the button twice, it gets called for another even if the first is still executing or running.

This produces a problem (if I am correct), and that is: it stops execution for the first one and starts executing for the other. How can I stop this calling of views twice?

Answer (score 0):

When a request has been sent to the server, Django will pick it up and send a response when it's finished. if there is no one there to receive the response then nothing happens but the processes have been done already. You should ask for verification if your process is important to be received.

When the user sends the second request, both requests will be processed and will return a response. If you're working with an API and your frontend isn't rendered in the backend server then the user will probably receive both responses and depending on the code on the front side, many things can happen. they might see both responses or just one. or the first one might get updated instantly when the second response comes in.

This might lead to problems depending on the processes you are running. for example, if you are updating a record in a database and the update can only happen once, then probably you'll get an error in the second try. it is really really rare and mostly impossible that the update part for both requests happens in the exact same time depending on your database, your code, and many other things.

There are many ways to handle such a problem which most of them depends on many things but I'm gonna list you few of these options:

1 - Change the display for the button to `none` so the user won't be able to click on it again. This is a very simple solution and works most of the times unless you have users trying to hurt your system intentionally.

2 - Redirect the user to another page and then wait for a response there.

3 - If your view is doing some heavy processes which are expensive to run, then just create a queue system with some limitations for each user. This is usually done in scaled projects with a lot of users.

4 - Use a rate limiting system to deny too many requests at once or block any none normal traffic.

Answer (score 0):

my advice, use jquery

```
$("btnSubmit").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
//disable the submit button
$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", true);
// call ur view using ajax here 
});
```

and then after ajax ended activate the button

```
$("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
```

Comment: and what about the non-button elements??

Comment: You can add an atribute to the tag with the value equal to the count number, every time that user clicks, check the count number if it is bigger than one do not proccess his request and after that the ajax request ended, set the count number to zero  so he can request again